# How to update controls[DataGrid,TextBoxes and Label] based on a row selection made in DataGrid that resideds in a updatePanel?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have got a grid[Grid1] that build its dataRows when a button[search] is clicked, I managed to Ajaxify it by placing it in an UpdatePanel and it worked fine. Before Ajaxifying Grid 1, another grid[Grid2] and some other controls[Text and Labels] used to get populated/updated when a row in Grid 1 was clicked .

The Grid2 and other controls used to get populated/updated on the OnItemCommand Event of Grid 1.Its the code in the OnItemCommand that binds the related data to Grid2 and other controls.

After I placed the Grid 1 in the update panel,they stopped updating. It will work  fine if I place Grid2 and other controls in the same Update Panel but the page is designed in a way that I cant have those controls in the same UpdatePanel as the first Grid nor I dont intend to use another Update Panel.

I hope I'm making some sense. I'm a newbie in .Net so please excuse. Please find the code below.

```
 <asp:ScriptManager EnablePartialRendering="true" ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers ="True">
      <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:DataGrid ID="grdJobs" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" 
        AlternatingItemStyle-CssClass="gridAltItemStyle"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="0" 
        DataKeyField="code"
        CssClass="datagridBox" 
        GridLines="horizontal" 
        PagerStyle-Mode="NumericPages"
        HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridHeaderStyle" 
        ItemStyle-CssClass="gridItemStyle"
        PagerStyle-CssClass="gridPagerStyle" 
        Width="445px" OnPageIndexChanged="grdJobs_PageIndexChanged" OnItemCreated="grdJobs_ItemCreated" OnItemCommand="grdJobs_ItemCommand"             OnItemDataBound="grdJobs_ItemDataBound">
         <Columns>
          <asp:BoundColumn  DataField="J_ID" HeaderText="Job"></asp:BoundColumn>
          <asp:BoundColumn  DataField="Contract" HeaderText="Contract" ReadOnly="True"></asp:BoundColumn>
          <asp:BoundColumn  DataField="J_Fault_Line1" HeaderText="Fault" ReadOnly="True"></asp:BoundColumn>
          <asp:BoundColumn  DataField="j_p_id" HeaderText="Fault" Visible="false" ></asp:BoundColumn>
          <asp:ButtonColumn Text="<img src=images/addFeedback.gif style=border: 0px; alt=Add Feedback>" ButtonType="LinkButton"  HeaderText="Add"                   CommandName="Load" ItemStyle-cssClass="Col_9_Item_2"></asp:ButtonColumn>
         </Columns>
        </asp:DataGrid>
       <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdLkp"  ImageUrl="Images/search.gif" runat="server" OnClick="cmdLkp_Click" />

       </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The code below in the code behind stopped working

```
protected void grdJobs_ItemCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CommandName == "Load")
        {
            functionToBindDataToGrid2();
            functionToBindDataToOtherControls();
        }
}

 protected void grdJobs_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
    {
      e.Item.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:__doPostBack('grdJobs$ctl" + ((Convert.ToInt32(e.Item.ItemIndex + 3).ToString("00"))) + "$ctl00','')");
     }
```

Comment: When you say you want to "force a postback," do you mean that after clicking a row in Grid1, you want Grid1 to do some work within the update panel, then the page performs a full postback, and upon reloading of the page, Grid2 gets updated?

Comment: @Alison please ignore the force postback bit.There are some lines of code that binds data to Grid2 in functionToBindDataToGrid2(),they are not working,they worked before I put Grid 1 in UpdatePanel. The data in Grid2 is based on the selection[via clicking the row] made in Grid 1. If you want I can post that code as well for you to have a look.Hope im making some sense

Comment: This is a tricky situation.  You are performing a partial postback of the UpdatePanel which will only update content that is inside of the update panel.  Without a full postback, content outside of the updatepanel simply won't be updated.  Is there a reason why you don't want to put Grid2 inside another UpdatePanel?  It is not ideal but it should solve your problems.

Comment: @Alison I know its tricky,the page is designed in a way such that you cant have the Grid2 in the same updatePanel.Yes it would work if i was to put it in the same update Panel or if i was to put Grid 2 in a separate update Panel.I have seen articles online how to update a single label or a single text control using RegisterDataIteme outside an UpdatePanel but nothing related to Grids.And I have got a dozen text/label controls to fill.

Comment: I was looking something similar to this but for grids http://www.aspnetajaxtutorials.com/2011/02/scriptmanagerregisterdataitem-to-update.html

Comment: Wait, so what's wrong with putting grid2 in another update panel if you said it would work?  What are the results, and better yet, what do you not like about the results?

Comment: @Fritos Its not that something was wrong,I just wanted to know if Grid2 could be updated by not placing it in an update Panel.Because I know a label outside the updatePanel can be updated.i was wondering if the same could be possible with Grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A GridView is a complex asp.net server control.  You will have a lot of difficulty updating Grid2 after Grid1 is updated inside of the UpdatePanel.  However, it is possible to a execute JavaScript on the client after Grid1 is updated.  You could update Grid1 inside of the update panel, execute JavaScript after Grid1 has been updated that will update HTML on the page.  The problem is that updating Grid2 with Javascript is going to be a nightmare amount of work.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about: [Ajax Enabled Gridview using JavaScript in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/JavaScriptGridView.aspx).  It is a total hack, a huge amount of work, and your co-workers will hate you when they have to maintain it.

If you wanted to update a label or a dropdown list then that would be possible but updating a GridView using Javascript and having those updates persist across postbacks is a daunting challenge.

Comment: The important point in the above is 'having those updates persist across postbacks...'. The way I'd approach this is to have the 'child' grid always built up from the client using a client-side JS template and JSON. Quite a lot for the newbie developer to get his head round, but it can give easily maintainable code. Having done this, of course, solving the initial problem is trivial.

Comment: I agree that there are many "better" ways to do this and it would take an experienced front & back end developer to make this happen.  Putting Grid2 inside an updatepanel would solve all of the OP's problems.  What we really should all be discussing is why he can't use updatepanel and then solve that problem.

Comment: sorry i was late in replying to your answer,i owe u 75 points.I had to make it work by placing both Grids in the updatePanel,like you said it was a daunting callenge to update a Grid using javascript...

Comment: @manraj82: No problem.  I wish I had a better answer for you than "don't do it.  It can't be done."

Answer (score 4):

In the properties for the UpdatePanel, set the update mode to "Conditional" and ChildrenAsTriggers to "true".

Another option would be to move the button inside the update panel so that you wouldn't have to have the trigger.

Comment: @epotter thanks for ur advice but it didnt work.The trigger is working fine, its the events in the Grid that are not working.They used to work before I placed them in the UpdatePanel

Comment: @manraj82 The important part of it's answer is to set `ChildrenAsTriggers="true"`.

Comment: guys it still not working,i tried ur advice but no luck.When i hover the mouse over the button column i can see __doPostBack() but it doesnnt seem to do anything,earlier the grid used to do a post back and populate the second grid and controls. Have you got any links to tutorials or articles focussing on datagrids in an update panel

Comment: @epotter <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="grdJobs"/>, this got it working,it was not doing the postBack,once I added this code it started doing the PostBack.Do u think I will still need ChildrenAsTriggers="False" UpdateMode="Conditional" ??

Comment: @manray82 - If you set a breakpoint in grdJobs_ItemCommand, does it get hit if you click the button in the row?

Comment: yea u r right,I got the "Invalid postback or callback argument" error.What Im trying to do is a "Search",the user types in a text and seraches for it,and the grid populates it with the results.After I included the <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="grdJobs"/> code,it worked fine for the first search but then started throwing the above error for the results of the second search

Comment: @epotter is there anyway of doing a postBack?I need to do a postBack when clicked on the rows of the Grid..

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple UpdatePanels on one page.  It won't affect the layout.

You can then use triggers (for the panels) in order to affect which controls you want affected.

Here's a page that will help you understand.

http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is down to the way you are triggering the postback on row click, i.e.: this method

```
protected void grdJobs_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
  e.Item.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:__doPostBack('grdJobs$ctl" + ((Convert.ToInt32(e.Item.ItemIndex + 3).ToString("00"))) + "$ctl00','')");
}
```

Manually writing the `__doPostBack` script is generally always a bad idea.  I believe what you need to use instead is [ClientScriptManager.GetPostBackEventReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153112.aspx) which will create a similar looking postback script for you, but will take into account all sorts of other things including AJAX-ification of the control.

Try something like this instead:

```
protected void grdJobs_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
  e.Item.Attributes.Add("onclick", ClientScriptManager.GetPostBackEventReference(e.Item, string.Empty);
}
```