# Will DataGrid Events stop firing once the grid is placed in an UpdatePanel?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, datagrid, updatepanel, postback

Will DataGrid Events like `OnPageIndexChanged,OnItemCreated,OnItemCommand,OnItemDataBound`
 stop firing once the grid is placed in an UpdatePanel?

Comment: @Akram yes I do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950206/events-in-datagrid-not-firing-after-being-put-in-the-updatepanel this is my problem,thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to register each and every LinkButton (I'm asssuimg you're using a LinkButton) as an AsyncPostBackTrigger. After each row is bound in your DateGrid (ie: onRowDataBound), you'll need to search for the LinkButton and register it through code as follows:

```
LinkButton lb = e.Row.FindControl("MarkAsCompleteButton") as LinkButton;  
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lb)
```

Comment: thanks 4 ur answer,then why is that this piece of code ***e.Item.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:__doPostBack('grdJobs$ctl" + ((Convert.ToInt32(e.Item.ItemIndex + 3).ToString("00"))) + "$ctl00','')");*** dont work which I have in the OnItemDataBound event?